# ZipOutputStream to network

Tags: java, performance, networking, optimization, zip

I want the ability to read multiple data streams over network and write a file to network combining all these multiple files.

Since the files could be very huge, I do not want to do any local IO file operation, rather operate on stream of data.
Read stream from network, write stream to network as zip.

I am trying the below sample code, but I do not see any file being written on the remote host. 
Instead of writing over network, if I use `FileInputStream` then writting to local disk file works.

What am i missing to write to network ?

```
   InputStream input = new URL("http://www.cacr.caltech.edu/projects/danse/talks/kickoff/07-Butler/SANS_DANSEkickoffAug06.pdf").openStream();



    URL url = new URL("http://posttestserver.com/post.php?dir=ziptest");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);

    ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());



   zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("1.pdf"));

    byte[] buffer = new byte[0xFFFF];



    for (int len; (len = input.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
        zipOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }


    zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("2.pdf"));

    InputStream input1 = new URL("http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf").openStream();

    for (int len; (len = input1.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
        zipOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }



    zipOutputStream.close();

    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("HTTP response code="+responseCode);

    connection.disconnect();
```

Comment: You aren't calling `ZipOutputStream.closeEntry()`. Flush after the loops, not inside them. I can see three files at http://posttestserver.com/data/2017/10/26/ziptest/, but they look a bit short.

Comment: @EJP Both `putNextEntry()` and `close()` automatically calls `closeEntry()` if needed. --- No need to `flush()`, ever.

Comment: @Andreas Agreed, and certainly not inside loops.

Comment: @EJP : I removed the `flush()` but the result is same as to no file getting generated.

Comment: @NoviceUser I didn't say it would fix anything. It's just poor practice to flush inside loops. Did you check any of the files at the link I gave you?

Comment: @EJP : Thanks for clarifying and for the pointer. Yes, I did check the folder, and those are not the files uploaded by me. Probably someone else reading the code tried something at their end.

Comment: That's only possible if this isn't your real code. Otherwise it would work the same for everybody, even you.

Comment: I don't know what program they are trying, but above code does not work for me. Also as you can see the file size is very less.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't doing any input, so nothing actually happens. You need at least to get the HTTP response code:

```
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("HTTP response code="+responseCode);
```

Better still, read the input or the error stream, as appropriate, and then close it.

**EDIT** Have you considered examining the files? Here's one I just created:

```
Time: Thu, 26 Oct 17 05:36:04 +0000
Source ip: 107.23.92.82

Headers (Some may be inserted by server)
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = en
HTTP_HOST = posttestserver.com
HTTP_CONNECTION = Keep-Alive
HTTP_USER_AGENT = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2b5) Gecko/20091204 Firefox/3.6b5
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = gzip,deflate
REMOTE_ADDR = 107.23.92.82
DOCUMENT_ROOT = /var/www/html
REQUEST_SCHEME = http
CONTEXT_PREFIX = 
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT = /var/www/html
REMOTE_PORT = 52482
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = CGI/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD = GET
QUERY_STRING = dir=ziptest
REQUEST_URI = /post.php?dir=ziptest
PHP_SELF = /post.php
REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT = 1508996164.351
REQUEST_TIME = 1508996164

No Post Params.
Empty post body.
```

You need to write the body as name-value paired parameters, e.g. 'zipfile=.................'. How that will play with binary data following is anybody's guess. Strictly speaking you should URL-encode the data. But what is really required depends on how your target system behaves. Quite possibly you should be using PUT instead of POST.

Comment: Getting the response code as 200, but still no file at http://posttestserver.com/data/2017/10/26/ziptest/

Comment: Maybe you're hitting a size limit. Try something smaller.

Comment: I used small PDF's, but still no luck.

Comment: See edit. I also succeeded just by setting chunked transfer mode, don't know why.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I created my local PHP based upload server and the code works. However I get OOM error when running for big files java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
 at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
 at

Comment: That's another reason to use chunked transfer mode.